# Limit number of inputs in a file Java

Tags: java, file-io, io, terminate

In this program I am trying to randomly generate names, airport destination/arrival and the day they fly there along with the time. I am running into issues when it comes to terminating the program when the number of lines in the file is more than 10000 entries and less than 100,000 entries. One of the solutions I came up with was making an array called minimumInputs. This is equal to the number of airports that are available. In the flightManifest method I make sure to add the number of entries that are equal to the number of seats that are generated for a given plane. I just cant figure out how to make it stop once every airport file reaches 10,000 but no more than 100,000 entries. Thanks everyone for their help!

EDIT: FIXED! Here is the edited while loop to fix the problem.

```
while (minimumInputs[0] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[1] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[2] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[3] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[4] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[5] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[6] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[7] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[8] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[9] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[10] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[11] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[12] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[13] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[14] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[15] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[16] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[17] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[18] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[19] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[20] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[21] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[22] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[23] < numberOfEntries && minimumInputs[24] < numberOfEntries) {
            flightManifest();
        }

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class OLE1 {

    static String[] airports = {"LAX", "MSP", "FAR", "ATL", "ORD", "DFW", "DEN", "JFK", "SFO", "CLT", "LAS", "PHX", "IAH", "MIA", "PEK", "CAN", "HND", "HKG", "SIN", "LHR", "CDG", "LGW", "MUC", "FRA", "EDI"};
    static final int numberOfEntries = 10000;
    static String[] firstNames = {"Isis", "Donnette", "Reyes", "Willis", "Kathy", "Elizbeth", "Long", "Jim", "Devorah", "Magda", "Maryetta", "Keturah", "Corrinne", "Shena", "Xiao", "Otha", "Hallie", "Pennie", "Dong", "Kristopher", "Eveline", "Ardella", "Tien", "Tianna", "Loren", "Many", "Anjelica", "Cecile", "Mae", "Jenae", "Sonya", "Dotty", "Florance", "Mittie", "Katia", "Nena", "Lu", "Janee", "Armando", "Leandro", "Claris", "Claudine", "Moriah", "Eddie", "Susan", "Rhoda", "Monnie", "Emelia", "Cory", "Ying"};
    static String[] lastNames = {"Belva", "Nam", "Liz", "Jeanett", "Corine", "Abe", "Olga", "Olevia", "Ernestine", "Joanne", "Sharyn", "Heidi", "Zachariah", "Sylvester", "Luetta", "Stephaine", "Garrett", "Debby", "Judi", "Noe", "Maybelle", "Eldora", "Roseann", "Madge", "Glayds", "Eleonore", "Josephine", "Quincy", "Alyson", "Earlene", "Clementina", "Jeri", "Kristel", "Carrol", "Zona", "Eileen", "Margherita", "Joline", "Terence", "Christinia", "Eldon", "Arleen", "Aimee", "Chanda", "Carin", "Prudence", "Tanja", "Kathlene", "Kareen", "Geneva"};
    static String[] middleInitial = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    static int minimumInputs[] = new int[25];
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the airplane program. This program will go ahead and create a list of all the passengers that have gone through 25 different airports.");
        System.out.println("The list of the airports we keep track of are listed below\n");
        int count = 0;

        //for listing out the airport names
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print(airports[count]);
            count++;
            System.out.print(" | " + airports[count]);
            count++;
            System.out.print(" | " + airports[count]);
            count++;
            System.out.print(" | " + airports[count]);
            count++;
            System.out.println(" | " + airports[count]);
            count++;
        }
    /*  
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            if (flightSeatingAmount() >= 850) {
                System.out.println("check this" + flightSeatingAmount());
            }
            System.out.println(flightSeatingAmount());

        }
    */

        //Need to add it so its not more than 100,000 entries in a file.
        while(minimumInputs[0] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[1] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[2] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[3] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[4] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[5] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[6] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[7] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[8] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[9] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[10] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[11] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[12] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[13] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[14] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[15] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[16] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[17] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[18] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[19] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[20] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[21] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[22] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[23] < numberOfEntries || minimumInputs[24] < numberOfEntries) {
            flightManifest();
        }

        System.out.println("The files have been compiled.");

    }

    public static int flightSeatingAmount() {
        int flight = (int)(50 + (Math.random() * 800));
        return flight;
    }

    public static String nameGenerator() {
        String names = "";
        int firstAndLast = (int)(Math.random() * 50);
        int initial = (int)(Math.random() * 26);
        names = lastNames[firstAndLast] + "," + firstNames[firstAndLast] + "," + middleInitial[initial];
        return names;
    }

    public static int airportSelectionOne() {
        int airportOne = (int)(Math.random() * (25 - 1));
        return airportOne;
    }

    public static int airportSelectionTwo() {
        int airportTwo = (int)(Math.random() * (25 - 1));
        return airportTwo;
    }

    public static int flightTimeIntervalMinutes() {
        int timing[] = {15, 30, 45, 00};
        int randomTiming = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
        return timing[randomTiming];
    }

    public static int flightTimeIntervalHours() {
        int timing = (int)(Math.random() * 24);
        return timing;
    }

    public static int flightDuration() {
        int duration = 0;

        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 0 && airportSelectionOne() <= 13 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 14 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 18) {
            duration = 22;
        }   
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 0 && airportSelectionOne() <= 13 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 19 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 24) {
            duration = 9;
        }
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 14 && airportSelectionOne() <= 18 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 0 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 13) {
            duration = 22;
        }
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 14 && airportSelectionOne() <= 18 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 19 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 24) {
            duration = 10;
        }
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 19 && airportSelectionOne() <= 24 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 0 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 13) {
            duration = 9;
        }
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 19 && airportSelectionOne() <= 24 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 14 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 18) {
            duration = 10;
        }
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 0 && airportSelectionOne() <= 10 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 0 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 13) {
            duration = 3;
        }
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 14 && airportSelectionOne() <= 18 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 14 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 18) {
            duration = 2;
        }
        if (airportSelectionOne() >= 19 && airportSelectionOne() <= 24 && airportSelectionTwo() >= 19 && airportSelectionTwo() <= 24) {
            duration = 2;
        }

        return duration;
    }


    public static void flightManifest() throws IOException {

        String departure = airports[airportSelectionOne()];
        String arrival = airports[airportSelectionTwo()];

        PrintWriter outputFileDeparture = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(departure.toLowerCase() + ".txt", true));
        PrintWriter outputFileArrival = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(arrival.toLowerCase() + ".txt", true));

        minimumInputs[airportSelectionOne()] = minimumInputs[airportSelectionOne()] + flightSeatingAmount();
        minimumInputs[airportSelectionTwo()] = minimumInputs[airportSelectionTwo()] + flightSeatingAmount();
        int day = (int)(Math.random() * 21);

        int flightHours = flightTimeIntervalHours();
        int flightMinutes = flightTimeIntervalHours();

        for (int i = 0; i <= flightSeatingAmount(); i++) {
            String passengersName = nameGenerator();
            int arrivalHour = (flightHours + flightDuration());

            if(arrivalHour > 24) {
                arrivalHour = arrivalHour - 24;
            }

            outputFileDeparture.println(passengersName + "," + "0" + "," + departure + "," + String.format("%02d", day) + flightHours + flightMinutes);
            outputFileArrival.println(passengersName + "," + "1" + "," + arrival + "," + String.format("%02d", day) + (flightHours + flightDuration()) + flightMinutes);
            //System.out.println(count);
            //count++;
        }

        outputFileDeparture.close();
        outputFileArrival.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this codes compiles?

Comment: Yes when I compile the program runs perfectly, it keeps running and the files end up with over 100,000 lines each.

Comment: I suggest you post this at [Codes Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: They don't look at code to debug them sadly.

Comment: Ok then, lets do this. will be back in 1 1/2 hour. lunch time

Comment: Right, it seems that your `while` loop is running infinite. perhaps you dont need to use `minimumInput` array

Comment: also what `numberOfEntries` which is `10000` suppose to do?

Comment: @Rafa El Basically a file cannot contain less than 10,000 lines and no more than 100,000. The numberOfEntries is to make sure that that minimum requirement is met.

Comment: I have figured it out. Thanks for your help Rafa, I just needed to modify the while loop. I will post it above.

Comment: Ok then. Now you can [ask for a review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since I believe that your code still can be simplified much

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment yet :(

Couldn't you use a do-while loop? You'd override the math method for a minimum integer and modify that method so that it would fit your likings. And then do the same for the max number. Then say while (num > min && < max)

?

I'm not sure if this is 100% plausible, but it may work...